# Azure DevOps does not updates Container Registry on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, docker-registry

I'm trying to perform CI/CD via Azure DevOps by using docker container for my React Application.

So here is my Docker File:

```
WORKDIR app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build 

FROM nginx:1.19

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

[And Here is my Azure DevOps Pipeline:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjdEg.png)

My container registry on Azure called app.
Please help me, maybe anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: What is the error on the pipeline?

Comment: There is no error, build completed successfully, but changes are not applied to container registry after git push.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in the Dockerfile path. I see you're using the GitHub repo as an artifact for the pipeline, but you are not referencing the artifact in the Dockerfile parameter's value.

The correct value for that parameter should be

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_EugeneKuhot_GrandSchool_MVP/<PATH_FOR_THE_DOCKERFILE_IN_YOUR_PROJECT>/Dockerfile
```

or something similar. Next to the parameter field there's a contextual menu (three dots) you can click on and will let you choose the correct path for the Dockerfile in your artifact.

Comment: I don't think that issue in Dockerfile path. If it was so, I'll have and error in build logs, but build is completing successfully. Also, I chose a path exactly in a same way you mentioned (using three dots context menu).
Possibly, there is an issue in "Container repository field", because I don't know the correct value for it. I've put my container registry name in this field, but I'm not sure that it's a correct way.

Comment: The "Container repository" is just the "Name of the repository". If it doesn't exist, it's going to be created, so that shouldn't be an issue. Have you checked if the Container Registry field has the correct value.